# Change textsize and generell size according to windows scaling | Flutter

Tags: windows, flutter, screen, scaling

Good Morning,
in the following to pictures you can see my problem.
The first one is a screenshot of my flutter website with a windows scale of 100%. (display settings of windows).

The second one is a screenshot of my flutter website with a windows scale of 125%.
Well, as you might know I want to adjust my textsize and the generell size of e.g. container to the windows screen scaling.

[image]

[image]

For my fonts I'm using following code:

```
ThemeData.dark().copyWith(
        scaffoldBackgroundColor: bgColor,
        textTheme: GoogleFonts.poppinsTextTheme(Theme.of(context).textTheme).apply(bodyColor: Colors.white),
        canvasColor: secondaryColor,
```

For all other values I use fixed numbers.
Thanks for any kind of help.